# can't run jboss from command prompt using run.bat

Tags: jboss

when i execute run.bat from \jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin 
i get following error

```
Calling D:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\run.conf.bat
Could not locate "D:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\bin\run.jar".
Please check that you are in the bin directory when running this script.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set

> JBOSS_HOME = D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin

Please make sure you didn't make any modifications related to JBOSS_HOME in run.conf.bat

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. To solve it I set `JBOSS_HOME` to the bin directory.
Set it to the parent directory of the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JBOSS_HOME environment variable. make sure its point to your jboss home directory for e.g. in my case D:\jboss-5.0.0.CR2